# How to split String in java with question marks, points and exclamation marks

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

How to split this into a String array using delimiters as question marks, points, and exclamation marks. And then put a space before every uppercase character. After which make that characters lowercase.

```
String one = "ATrueRebelYouAre!EveryoneWasImpressed.You'llDoWellToContinueInTheSameSpirit?";
```

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  This sounds like an assignment to me.

Comment: I was trying 2 days. I'm so tired of this. I tried spitting with regex, I tried the replace method, I tried to convert a string in to char array.

Comment: At least, edit your question and show a sample input covering all the cases, along with the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

For splitting with multiple delimiters, you could use the regex OR operator:

```
String[] tokens = one.split("\\?|\\.|\\!");
```

To put a space before every uppercase you could do:

```
String two = "";
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    String phrase = tokens[i];
    String outputString = "";
    for (int k = 0; k < phrase.length(); k++) {
        char c = phrase.charAt(k);
        outputString += Character.isUpperCase(c) ? " " + c : c;
    }
two += outputString + " ";
}
two = two.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

That will print the following:

```
A True Rebel You Are Everyone Was Impressed You'll Do Well To Continue In The Same Spirit
```

But you could also do something like this:

```
String two = "";
for (int k = 0; k < one.length(); k++) {
    char c = one.charAt(k);
    two += Character.isUpperCase(c) ? " " + c : c;
}
two = two.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
System.out.println(two);
```

Which will print this:

```
A True Rebel You Are! Everyone Was Impressed. You'll Do Well To Continue In The Same Spirit?
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Also how after this make all the letters except the first one lowercase?

Comment: You could do just like you answered, or you could set everything to lowerCase then you find the indexes of the delimiters and change the first letter after them to uppercase

Answer (score 0):

Using [zero-width assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Where ?= is a positive lookahead, and ?<= is negative one. We can use it in a stream as follows:

```
    List<String> collect = Arrays.stream(one.split("(?<=[?.!])"))
    .map(sentence -> sentence.replaceAll("(?=[A-Z])", " ").trim() )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The result is as follows:

```
[A True Rebel You Are!, Everyone Was Impressed., You'll Do Well To Continue In The Same Spirit?]
```

Answer (score -1):

Did it!

```
    String one = "ATrueRebelYouAre!EveryoneWasImpressed.You'llDoWellToContinueInTheSameSpirit?";

    String oneWithSpaces = one.replace("!","! ").replace("?","? ").replace(".",". ");
    String[] splitedWithDelimeters = oneWithSpaces.split(" ");


    for (int j = 0; j < splitedWithDelimeters.length; j++) {

        String[] str = splitedWithDelimeters[j].split("(?=[A-Z])");



        for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                System.out.print(str[i] + " ");
            } else if (i > 0) {
                System.out.print(str[i].toLowerCase() + " ");
            }
        }
    }
```